# enter a command using python when ready while reading serial from arduino

Tags: python

I was trying to send a command to arduino using python program. but I also want to program to read the serial output coming from the arduino.
This is my python program:

```
import wx, wx.html
import sys
import time
import serial
import smtplib
import msvcrt

TO = '*******@yahoo.com'
GMAIL_USER = 's****l@gmail.com'
GMAIL_PASS = '****'

SUBJECT = 'Planters Hall room Temperature'
TEXT = 'The Temperature rise up to 28C!. The AC will now switched automatically'

SUBJECT2 = 'Planters Hall room Temperature'
TEXT2 = 'The Temperature was now stable'

ser = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600)
a = 0

def send_email():
    print("Sending Email")
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASS)
    header = 'To:' + TO + '\n' + 'From: ' + GMAIL_USER
    header = header + '\n' + 'Subject:' + SUBJECT + '\n'
    print header
    msg = header + '\n' + TEXT + ' \n\n'
    smtpserver.sendmail(GMAIL_USER, TO, msg)
    smtpserver.close()

def send_email2():
    print("Sending Email")
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASS)
    header = 'To:' + TO + '\n' + 'From: ' + GMAIL_USER
    header = header + '\n' + 'Subject:' + SUBJECT2 + '\n'
    print header
    msg = header + '\n' + TEXT2 + ' \n\n'
    smtpserver.sendmail(GMAIL_USER, TO, msg)
    smtpserver.close()

while True:

  while a == 0:
    message = ser.readline()
    print(message)
    if message[0] == 'M' :
      send_email()
      time.sleep(0.5)

    if message[0] == 'S' :
      send_email2()
      time.sleep(0.5)


    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        a=1


  while a == 1:
     key = msvcrt.getch()
     if key == '\r':
         b = raw_input("Enter Message:")
         ser.write(b)
         a = 0
```

but the problem is the > ("Enter Message:") will only show up after a reading from an arduino came up.

Comment: Can you please add a direct copy-paste of your actual code? This example will not compile because it is incorrectly indented.

Comment: Put your reading code in a separate thread of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to run your example, but serial.readline does block if no timeout is specified.

The docs are here: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline

Comment: i got this error when i added timeout  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JohnC\Desktop\AC control2.py", line 65, in <module>
    if message[0] == 'M' :
IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: The memory at that index is null because ser.readline timed out and memory[0] was never assigned. You need to encapsulate anything in scope following ser.readline with a null reference check on message[index].